# no wifi adaptor found for hp15da0327tu

Tags: 18.04, drivers, hp, ubuntu-drivers

I have installed ubuntu 18.04 onto hp laptop within modal hp15da0327tu and the kernel version of my system is 5.3.0-28-generic.
but I'm not able to use wifi internet.
please help me with this.

Comment: FYI: You are using a EOL kernel, a fully upgraded Ubuntu 18.04 system should be using the 5.4 kernel (as 5.3 is EOL).  Have you not upgraded via ethernet? or are you using something other than Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (as 5.3 is unsupported)

Comment: I'm using ubuntu only and i also upgraded via ethernet but when i update kernel version it was not taking boot so i have to remove version 5.4

Comment: What is your output of 'lspci -k | grep Network'?

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems getting WiFi to work with countless laptops and versions of Ubuntu down the years.

After much time wasted trying to fix this I eventually bought one of these:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/TP-Link-TL-WN823N-Wireless-Supports-10-9-10-13/dp/B0088TKTY2

I have never looked back.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your kernel version with `uname -r`, then

1. `sudo apt install linux-headers git build-essential wget unzip dkms` (linux-headers of installed kernel version, you may use synaptic package manager)
2. `wget -d -c -O 'rtl8723de.zip' https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de/archive/4.11-up.zip` to download the driver zip file for kernel version 4.11 and up
3. `unzip rtl8723de.zip` shall unzip the driver folder
4. `cd rtl8723de` will take you to the respective directory
5. `make && sudo make install` shall install the driver
6. `sudo reboot`

P.S. If you're using kernel version 4.10 or down then `wget -d -c -O 'rtl8723de.zip' https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de/archive/4.10-down.zip` shall give you the driver file

Hope it helps